# Capturing three regions with awk

Tags: awk

I want to able to match the following lines in a file using a regular exprossion

```
## FAML [ASMB]

## FAML [ASMB] KYA

## FAML [ASMB] KYA,KYB
```

and then be able to capture the values of `FAML`, `ASMB` and the sequence of comma separated keywords `KYA,KYB`.

The user supplies `FAML`, `ASMB`, and any keywords they want to match
for `KYA,KYB` etc.

I am doing

```
BEGIN {
  kw=".*" ; ebl="[[]" ; ebr="[]]" ; spc="[[:space:]]*"
  pn_ere = "^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|//)[[:space:]]+"
  fm = "%s(%s) %s(%s)%s(%s)%s$"
  beg_ere = sprintf(fm, pn_ere, faml, ebl, asmb, ebr, kw, spc)
}

$0 ~ beg_ere {
  fml = gensub(beg_ere, "\\2", 1, $0)
  asm = gensub(beg_ere, "\\3", 1, $0)
  kyw = gensub(beg_ere, "\\4", 1, $0)
 }
```

where `(%s)` are used to capture `fml`, `asm`, and `kyw` present in the file to match any user inputs to `faml`, `asmb`, and `kw`.

The line matches are to be performed upon source code files in the comment sections starting with double comment characters `##`, `;;`, `!!`, `//`, `@c`.

Thusly a user could call

```
awk -f densel -v faml="HD" -v asmb="OPCON" galex.el
```

For instance, consider an emacs lisp file `galex.el`.

```
;; HD [TEST]

(defun galex-insert (n)
  "Copy line N at current point.
N is the numeric prefix arg"
  (interactive "p")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (forward-line (1- n))
    (kill-ring-save (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))))

;; HD [OPCON]

(message "\nGALEX")

;; HD [OPCON] elisp,resource

(message "\nGALEX")
```

The regexp would then match the lines `;; HD [OPCON]` and `;; HD [OPCON] elisp,resource`.

And if the user specifies

```
awk -f densel -v faml="HD" -v asmb="OPCON" -v kw="resource"  galex.el
```

only the following line would match

```
;; HD [OPCON] elisp,resource
```

Comment: Can you please post **testable** code for questions like these - presumably the first group of statements are intended to be enclosed in a `BEGIN` block? Where are the definitions of `faml` and `asmb`?

Comment: Ditto for posting actual input data. It is unclear why `pn_ere` attempts to match any of `; ! @c //`. The variables faml, asmb and kw passed to sprintf are all empty strings.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us what problem you have with the code you posted, e.g. what it's doing that you don't want it to do or what it's not doing that you do want it to do. At a glance it looks like it'd match the lines you posted and populate `fml`, etc. as you say you want so it's not obvious what you're asking for help with and you didn't provide a complete script that we could test with to try to spot any issues ourselves.

Comment: `faml`, `asmb` and `kw` are supposed to be user inputs.  So in practice users supply them depending on what they want to match.

Comment: In a recent edit to the question, you say that the lines have to be matched in a certain context (inside the comment in a source code file), but you never show an example of that context with lines matching and not matching. It would be important to see this as the programming language and syntax of the source code is otherwise left unspecified.

Comment: I have now included an example elisp file.

Comment: Regarding [faml, asmb and kw are supposed to be user inputs.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736817/capturing-three-regions-with-awk#comment1399239_736817) - that's completely irrelevant to this question where you asked for help in `Capturing three regions with awk`.

Comment: If, once you implement the answer you got here to the question you asked here, you also need help prompting a user, reading their response, and passing those values to awk to do something with then ask a new question about that. And please stop significantly changing your question after you have answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't clear but this may be what you're trying to do (using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    re = "#+ ([^ ]+) ([[][^]]*]) *(.*)"
}
match($0,re,a) {
    for (i=1; i in a; i++) {
        print i, a[i]
    }
    print ""
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 FAML
2 [ASMB]
3

1 FAML
2 [ASMB]
3 KYA

1 FAML
2 [ASMB]
3 KYA,KYB
```

Obviously just assign whatever variables you like to the contents of `a[1]`, etc.

Change the regexp to suit your needs, this is just to demonstrate what I think is the problem and solution in a minimal way and to show you how to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if/when you need to ask additional questions in future.

See `match()` in https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions for what that function does.

Comment: The `re` must be user defined.  If the user does not supply values for `faml` and `asmb` they are to be defaulted to `[[:graph:]]+`.  A user can also define keywords in the `re` if one wants to.

Comment: The `re` here is sufficiently generic to cover all the use cases you have shown. If you allow "the user" to type an `re` you will get a 90% failure rate: you really need to simplify the UI, and construct the RE dynamically. You can do the defaulting in a BEGIN section (and I note this is rather late in the topic to add yet more requirements).

Comment: @Enver once again you're adding irrelevancies and unnecessarily complicating your question. Whether the re is user-defined or hard coded is irrelevant to the problem of `Capturing three regions with awk`, as is whether or not faml and asmb are to be defaulted to [[:graph:]]+. Just focus on 1 question/answer at a time - what I've shown in my answer is the solution to the problem you asked about of how to capture 3 regions with awk. You already know how to do all that other stuff as shown in your previous questions and none of it is related to this question.

Comment: `gensub` could be better suited for this because it is able to extract the parts in the `re` that within `( )` only.

Comment: I had hoped that you could modify `beg_ere` using the parameters in the `sprintf` part, rather than coming up with a completely different `re` that I cannot actually use.

Comment: Your code already contains 3 calls to `gensub()` - if you were happy with that then why ask the question? Also, as you can see in my answer, `match()` is also able to extract the parts in the re that within `( )` only but `match()` matches the whole regexp AND extracts all of the matches at once instead of what your existing code is doing where it has to do a separate comparison for the whole regexp and then match each part of it one at a time.

Comment: You CAN populate `beg_ere` using `sprintf()`, my answer has nothing to do with how you create the regexp, it's just focused on how to do what you asked for help with, i.e. `Capturing three regions with awk`. How you create the regexp is utterly irrelevant. Please take some time to really think about what the code in my answer is doing vs what your existing code is doing and keep in mind I'm only trying to answer the question you asked here, not provide all of the code for whatever your full script is supposed to do.

Comment: Then it was all a misunderstanding, as I wanted to fix the `beg_ere` as it is not working for the lines I want to match.  How I create the regexp is what is mostly important actually.  Will try to spend some hours to fix it, to avoid having too many questions about the same thing.

Comment: Yeah that wasn't at all clear, I thought you were asking how to improve `$0 ~ beg_ere {
  fml = gensub(beg_ere, "\\2", 1, $0)
  asm = gensub(beg_ere, "\\3", 1, $0)
  kyw = gensub(beg_ere, "\\4", 1, $0)
 }` as that's the part of your code that is `Capturing three regions with awk` as stated on your questions Subject line so that's what my answer does - shows a better way to do that.

Comment: I confirm that `match` handles regexp parentheses, such that the corresponding parenthesized subexpressions are inserted into an integer-indexed elements of an array. So you are correct in saying that I could replace gensub` with match.