# Capturing ## HD [OPCON] without keywords

Tags: awk

I have the following regular expression that I use in an awk file

```
beg_ere = "^[[:space:]]*([#;!/]{2}|@c)[[:space:]]+(HD) [[](OPCON)[]] .*[[:space:]]*$"
```

With it I am able to match the following lines

```
## HD [OPCON] this,that
## HD [OPCON] this,that,other
```

but not

```
## HD [OPCON]
```

How can I change `beg_ere` so I can match `## HD [OPCON]` as well ?

`this,that,other` are a series of keywords separated by commas.  There can be any number of keywords in a line, including none.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments under most of your other questions, please provide a minimal, complete script with concise testable sample input and expected output in your questions so it clarifies your needs and gives us something we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: Why do you think you must do everything with a single monster expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
beg_ere = "^[[:space:]]*([#;!/]{2}|@c)[[:space:]]+(HD) [[](OPCON)[]].*$"
```

Note: single space is removed before `.*`; Also removed redundant `[[:space:]]*` after that.

Comment: I need bracketing around the keywords so that I can capture them later with `gensub`.  I also need to allow possibility of having trialing spaces (which may happen in source code files).  But perhaps I can capture everything and remove the trailing spaces.

Comment: As demonstrated in [my answer to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/736826/133219), `gensub()` is the wrong function for what you're trying to do, you should be using `match()` instead.

Comment: `match` would split on spaces.  I want to capture parts using what happens to be inside `(...)` in the regular expression.  Or could it do that as well?

Comment: `match()` doesn't split on spaces. Maybe you're thinking of `split()` but even then it can do far more than split on spaces. The GNU awk (which you appear to already be using for `gensub()`) version of `match()` does exactly what you say you want to do, i.e. "capture parts using what happens to be inside `(...)` in the regular expression" as I clearly demonstrated in [my answer to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/736826/133219).

Comment: @Enver what is the `match`? what is the `gensub`? could you please edit your question and explain your exact need and how you are using them and why those are needed?

Comment: The answer is good for this question.  I can put a different one and explain the task associated with this.

Comment: @EdMorton Have looked at `match` upon your insistence, and you are absolutely right.  I could change to use `match`.